# Show $\sum_{p}\frac{\log(p)}{p(p-1)}$ and $\sum_{p}\left(\ln(1-\frac{1}{p})+\frac{1}{p}\right)$ converge.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $$\sum_{p}\frac{\log(p)}{p(p-1)}\quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{p}\left(\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ converge, where the sommation are for $p$ prime.

My ideas : for the first one $$\sum_{p}\frac{\log(p)}{p(1-p)}\leq \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log(n)}{n(n-1)}\leq \int_2^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x(x-1)}dx<+\infty .$$
Does it work ?

For the second one, I have no idea.

Comment: note: $ \left|\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{n} \right| < \frac{1}{n^2} $ for $n > 1.462$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, 
$$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log(n)}{n(n-1)}\leq \int_2^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x(x-1)}dx$$ is just a little bit off. In fact the reverse inequality holds. Your idea of using comparison between integral works, but it will be correct if you wrote
$$
\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log(n)}{n(n-1)}\leq \frac{\log 2}{2(2-1)}+ \int_2^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x(x-1)}dx.
$$

For the second one, use @Dando18's comment and comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Since for any $s>1$ we have

$$ \zeta(s)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1},\qquad \frac{d}{ds}\log\zeta(s)=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\sum_{p}\frac{\log p}{p^s-1} $$
the first series is bounded by $-\left(\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}+\frac{\zeta'(3)}{\zeta(3)}+\frac{\zeta'(5)}{\zeta(5)}\right)$.
Since $\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)+\frac{1}{p}\leq \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$, the second series is bounded by $-\frac{1}{2}\log\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{3}\log\zeta(3)$. Both approximations are pretty accurate.