# Constants $b$ and $C$ such that $|b-\sum_{p<n}\log(1-\frac{1}{p})+\frac{1}{p}|<\frac{C}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Im trying to show that there exist real numbers $b$ and $C$ such that
$|b-\sum_{p<n}\log(1-\frac{1}{p})+\frac{1}{p}|<\frac{C}{n}$ for any positive integers $n$, where $p$ represents a prime number.

So far, I've tried to find an upper bound for the sum, which I'll denote by $S_{n}$. I have that $\sum_{p<n}\log(1-\frac{1}{p}) \leq 0$ and also that $\sum_{p<n} < \sum_{k=1}^{n} = \log(n)+\gamma+O(\frac{1}{n})$. Combining this we get that $S_{n} <\log(n)+ \gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})$ but I'm not sure what to conclude from this. Is there something worth pursuing here?

My second though was to use this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196893/show-sum-p-frac-logppp-1-and-sum-p-left-ln1-frac1p-fra) to show that $S_{n}$ converges, then set $b=\lim S_{n}$. Then we can pick $\varepsilon > 0$ and get that $|b-S_{n}| < \varepsilon$ for all $n$ past some certain $N$, so setting $C = max_{1 \leq j \leq N}\{|b-S_{n}|+\varepsilon \}$ we have $|b-S_{n}|<C$ for all $n$. While this isn't the solution I feel like it might be moving in the right direction. Can I do better than this using convergence?

Comment: $\sum_{p> n} |\log(1-p^{-1})+p^{-1}|  \le \sum_{p\ge n}C p^{-2}\le \sum_{m\ge n} Cm^{-2} \le C n^{-2} +  C\int_n^\infty x^{-2}dx=Cn^{-2} +C n^{-1}$

Comment: So if I'm interpreting this correctly, we would have $b=lim S_{n}$ and $|b-S_{n}|=|\sum_{p>n}\log(1-p^{-1})+p^{-1}| \leq Cn^{-2}+Cn^{-1}$? Couldn't it then be that $Cn^{-1}<|b-S_{n}|<Cn^{-2}+Cn^{-1}$, or am I misunderstanding?